# Inconsistent free space

Tags: linux

Dolphin and df both say my root partition has 52GB free

```
$ df /
Filesystem     1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/nvme1n1p2 729661224 638789260  53760636  93% /
```

```
$ df -h /
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/nvme1n1p2  696G  610G   52G  93% /
```

```
$ sudo df /
Filesystem     1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/nvme1n1p2 729661224 638799708  53750188  93% /
```

[image: Dolphin properties window]

while KDE Partition Manager, Baobab, and Gnome Disks say I have 93GB
[image: KDE Partition Manager]
[image: Baobab]
[image: Gnome Disks]

This is very annoying, especially when I get a Low Disk Space warning after thinking that I have heaps of space free. I assume the correct number is 52GB, but how do I confirm this, and why do some give the wrong number?

**KDE Neon 5.27**

Comment: Many filesystems have reserved space that is only available to _root_.

Comment: What is the output of `df /`? (without `-h`). Please [edit] and post it [as text, not image](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4086/108618).

Comment: While at it, post the output of `df /` **and** `sudo df /`.

Comment: I've edited the post with new screenshots and the output of `df /`. I have freed up space since I posted so the numbers have changed

Comment: The output of `df /` and `sudo df /` is slightly different, but it is not 40GB different, so that doesn't seem to be the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You could check, if your filesystem fills up the whole partition. It is actually possible to have a filesystem that is smaller than your actual partition. This can easily happen, when one resizes a partition, but forgets to resize the filesystem as well.

To view your partition size, you might want to execute `sudo lsblk /dev/nvme1n1p2`. The column "SIZE" reports the actual partition size.

The get the size of your ext4 filesystem on that partition, you can follow [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/622489/how-to-find-the-size-of-a-filesystem). It basically suggests to use the `dumpe2fs` program and multiply the block-count with the block-size. You can clearly see those two values when you execute `sudo dumpe2fs -h /dev/nvme1n1p2 | grep Block`. The result of this will be in bytes and needs to be scaled for direct comparison with the partition size (e.g. divide it by 1048576 to get MiB).

If those two number differ by the ~40GB, than you know the cause for the reported discrepancy. You could resize your filesystem to put those remaining GB to use. For resizing an ext2/3/4 filesystem, a lot of tutorials are online. It basically boils down to use `resize2fs`. Resizing your root partition although might be a bit tricky, as usually those tutorials assume, that the partition can be unmounted for the resize to take place.

For completeness: the `dumpe2fs` and the `resize2fs` applications are contained in the `e2fsprogs` packages on Debian based systems. If you do not have those programs installed, install that package or lookup and install the correct package for your distribution.

Comment: The filesystem is the same size as the partition. The result of `sudo lsblk /dev/nvme1n1p2` is
`nvme1n1p2 259:2    0 707.5G  0 part /run/timeshift/backup`

and the result of `sudo dumpe2fs -h /dev/nvme1n1p2 | grep Block` is
`Block count:              185474816`
`Block size:               4096`

Comment: I just realized, that there is an easier way to compare filesystem an partition size: `sudo lsblk -b -o NAME,FSTYPE,SIZE,FSSIZE /dev/nvme0n1p2`. On my system, the two columns do not add up completely, therefore I'd assume the FSSIZE already has the filesystem's management overhead removed. This might also be a good way to see, if the management overhead is probably the reason for your diverging values.